# Discord.js | Assign specific roles uppon a user receiving other roles

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm developing a bot to work on a server which already uses other bots for role assignments and such. All I need it to do is to, whenever a user is assigned a specific role, give that same user another specific role. The other parts of the bot were figured out just fine, but I cannot seem to get this one straight. Does anyone know how to do it? Is it possible? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can track when a role is assigned with the `guildMemberUpdate` event.

```js
client.on('guildMemberUpdate', (oldMember, newMember) => {
  // first, make sure the role was assigned
  if (
    !oldMember.roles.cache.has('Role ID') &&
    newMember.roles.cache.has('Role ID')
  ) {
    newMember.roles.add('Role ID');
    // do something...
  };
});
```

Comment: `client.on('guildMemberUpdate', (oldMember, newMember) => {

    let firstrole = message.guild.roles.find(r => r.name === '780111045275942932');

    if (
        !oldMember.roles.cache.has(firstrole) &&
        newMember.roles.cache.has(firstrole)
    )   {

        let role = message.guild.roles.find(r => r.name === '737490175470600222');
        newMember.roles.add(role);
    };
  });`

This is probably a really dumb question, but how is this wrong?
At first it gave out a permission error, which I fixed. Now it doesn't show anything in the terminal, but just doesn't work.

Comment: `Collection.prototype.has()`, in this case, accepts the role ID, not the role object. There's no need to get the whole role or create variables for them, just use the IDs in the places I outlined.

Comment: Sorry about the crappy formatting, I'm still figuring that out. This is what I did at first, but still got no result:

`client.on('guildMemberUpdate', (oldMember, newMember) => {

    if (
        !oldMember.roles.cache.has('780111045275942932') &&
        newMember.roles.cache.has('780111045275942932')
    )   {

        newMember.roles.add('737490175470600222');
    };
  });`

Comment: I just noticed that my implementation was incorrect. Thanks for your help, it works just fine!